# Patterns and trends in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion

I am doing a project in which we're using the stack overflow data dump to analyze the trends and patterns of the site since it begins up until now. I am  going to visualize this trends later on and probably come with some conclusions on why this could happen. What sorts of question do you guys have in mind about stack overflow that would be nice to analyze on?

I'd actually like to know whether the question and answer are good quality or not... in other words comparing stackoverflow with wikipedia.. has anyone done a study on this before?

Comment: Look at data.stackexchange.com for the kind of queries that we use.

Comment: Also see [Greg Hewgill's site](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/).